# The relation $[X,Y]=fX+gY$ to be established for vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on a smooth manifold $M$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Why would smooth functions f and g exist so that $[X,Y]=fX+gY$ for vector fields $X,Y$ on a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$?
One starts to think of expanding the Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ in terms of the local expression of the vector fields $X=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x^j(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$, but how properly the functions $f$ and $g$ come out when
$$[X,Y](fg)=X(Y(fg))-Y(X(fg))= \cdots \quad 
\text{is used}$$ Perhaps not the right approach, please advise me.

Comment: This cannot be true, for example if $Y=0$ at a point $p$ while $[X, Y]\neq 0$ at $p$, this requires $[X, Y]$ be in the $X$ direction, which is not always the case.

Comment: I made several attempts to prove this. At the end, I concluded something is missing: either I don't know what is it or the question is not correcty set.

Answer (score 1):

As higlighted by @Yuval , the expression you are trying to prove is not true in general. In particular, we can say that it is true if and only if (by definition) the tangent distribution generated by the vector fields $X$ and $Y$ is **involutive**.

By distribution we mean the union, over all the points $m\in M$, of subspaces of the tangent spaces $T_mM$. In particular, in your case you have the distribution $\mathcal{D} := \cup_{m\in M}span\{X|_m,Y|_m\}$.

A simple example of non-involutive distribution on $M=\mathbb{R}^3$ is
$$ X=\partial_x,\quad Y = x\partial_z + \partial_y, $$
since if you compute $[X,Y]$ you get $\partial_z = [X,Y]$, which can not be expressed as a linear combination of the original fields $X$ and $Y$, and hence it does not belong to the tangent distribution generated by them.

However, in many books or online you can find many more examples.

Comment: Thanks, @Dadeslam, for your highlight. I will look for such.